# how to load database entries in a css container

Tags: php, css, mysql

I'm new to dynamic websites, i have a website that will have a list of artists in the form of cards, how do I load the database entries from MySQL so that they'd load exactly in this format and then auto load as i scroll? do i have to copy the container and reference the data with PHP in every single container?

```
 <div id="feed">
    <div class="feed_item">
        <div class="feed_img"></div>
        <h2 class="feed_title">Karamantoso</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="feed_item">
        <div class="feed_img"></div>
        <h2 class="feed_title">Yamyom</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="feed_item">
        <div class="feed_img"></div>
        <h2 class="feed_title">Hayom</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="feed_item">
        <div class="feed_img"></div>
        <h2 class="feed_title">Sha</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are new to dynamic websites you would want to load all of them at the same time. Then you'll move to paginate results and finally you will take a look at load them asynchronously with AJAX as you scroll. It´s not a simple task for newbies and these are things you need to know before moving into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pedro already said, I suggest you should first take a look at loading all of them at once before you have them on demand.

I can't really tell how far you progressed in PHP yet so I will just start explianing from where you process the query and store it in `$result`.

First of all you don't have to prepare the HTML before hand because that doesn't work for a dynamic amount of entries, so we want to avoid hard coding wherever possible. Instead we let PHP do that for us.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         //This gets executed for every MySQL entry
    }
}
```

Inside the while loop we can use just `echo` the entries to the HTML. The content for that we can get from `$row`:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     //This gets executed for every MySQL entry
     echo "<div class=\"feed_item\">";
     echo "<img src=\"" . $row['img'] . "\">";
     echo "<h2 class=\"feed_title\">" . $row['title'] . "</h2>";
     echo "</div>";
}
```

Keep in mind that for `$row['whatever']` you have to of course use your own rows you declared in your MySQL table.

All of that php stuff should go into your `feed` div:

```
<div id="feed">
    <?
        //Right here :)
    ?php>
</div>
```

So **once** you completely understood this, to load content on demand you'd probably have to use AJAX. A video that explains that really well imo is [this](https://youtu.be/rJesac0_Ftw). Even though the video is about JSONs stored on some webserver it also works for [PHP requests](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_database.asp)